# WLAN drivers not preinstalled! WiFi 5100AGN do not working

Tags: wireless, intel, adapter

I am a total newbie on ubuntu (linux).

I had installed three distributions and now i decided for ubuntu. Okay. 
But on every distribution my wlan adapater doesnt work well. My OS dont recognize the WLAN adapter and there aren't any drivers.

So i decided to search some drivers for Linux.

The WLAN chip is an Intel WiFi 5100AGN.

I found it on  http://intellinuxwireless.org/

The Download: http://intellinuxwireless.org/?n=downloads

Now, i have no plan how i could install the tar.gz

I had googled for installation tips but it doesnt function. Could anybody give me some advices for installing this tar.gz?

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: UPDATE:

Okay now i unpacked the *.ucode Data to lib/firmware/

But the data already exists...

So, the driver exists all the time since i have installed the ubuntu os

hmmmmmmmmmm

And why does Ubuntu do not recognize my WLAN adapter???

Damn!

Comment: To put it mildly, Intel's 5100AGN is problematic. I've [googled some useful links](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ubuntu+intel+5100agn) for you. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your .tar.gz on `/home/user` (the `user` is depend on your system settings). Then extract the tar files on that folder. After that, change your directory to that folder. Example if your folder name is `Wireless`, open terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+T`) then type this:

```
sudo cd /home/user/Wireless
```

Then type this command:

```
sudo make install
```

After that, restart your system to connect to the wireless network.